# Describe all tables to text file

Tags: postgresql

How can one describe every table in a database and export all the results to a text file?  E.g.

```
\o describe.txt
\d+ MY_TABLE
\o
```

but for every table, appending the output to the text file each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might want:

```
\dt+ *.*
```

i.e "all tables in all schemas". Use `\d` instead of `\dt` if you want to include views too.

I can't help wondering ... why? If you're doing this for documentation check out SchemaSpy as a much nicer alternative.

Comment: `\d+ *.*` was what I was after, and so was [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: As far as I can tell, SchemaSpy does not provide any diff functionality. The closest one I have found that has output suitable for diffing is [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/output.html). However, I still prefer the output of `\d+`.

Comment: thanks \d+ *.* gave me all table column details

Answer (score 1):

To get output by SQL query, please see below two ways:

(1) All column names and datatypes comma separated:

```
SELECT     
table_name, 
string_agg(column_name,',') as "Columns", 
string_agg(data_type ,',') as "DataTypes"
 FROM 
 information_schema.columns
 where "table_schema"='public'
  group by table_name
```

(2) All column names separately with datatypes

```
SELECT 
table_name, 
column_name as "Columns", 
data_type as "DataTypes"
 FROM 
 information_schema.columns
 where "table_schema"='public'
  order by table_name,column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all tables from a particular schema, for example the public schema run this:

```
 \d+ public.*
```